# .NET Core Ajax still redicted me to json response page

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I try to insert data to database with .NET Core Framework with AJAX hope this can return json response when it success, it success but i don't know it throws me to page fill it the response of json, not still in page when i insert the data. (sorry for link image, i'm not yet proper to upload image, stackoverflow say)

This is output i get;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7UY4.png

This is create in contoller;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0StbY.png

This is my javascript code;

```
var isDuplicate = true;
$("#formProduct").validate({
    rules: {
        NameProduct: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        }
    },
    messages: {
        NameProduct: {
            required: "Data tidak boleh kosong",
            minlength: "Minimal 5 huruf"
        }
    },
    submitHandler:function(form){
        debugger;
        if (isDuplicate) {
            return false;
        } else {
            submitAJAX(form);
        }
        debugger;
    }
});

function submitAJAX(form) {
    var fromData = new FormData();

    var dataForm = $(form).serializeArray();

    $.each(dataForm, function (key, input) {
        fromData.append(input.name, input.value);
    });

    var file = $("#ImageFile").prop("files");

    if (file.length > 0) {
        fromData.append("ImageFile", file[0]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Product/Create",
        data: fromData,
        method: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var data = response;
            if (data.success) {
                $("#modal_sm").modal("hide");
                toastr.success("Data success input");
                window.location.reload();
            }
            else {
                $("#modal_sm").modal("hide");
                toastr.error("Data failed input");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I hope can run ajax without get throw to page json result

Comment: Please, don't post links to screenshots. Either embed the images directly in the question or paste and format the text/code properly.

Comment: Hi @Andi, it is better for you to share the html code in your current view. Any way, I shared a working demo below you could check it and focus on the comment in js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you used `<input type="submit"/>` or `<button></button>` which will automatically submit the form when it is clicked.

Here is a whole working demo:

Model

```
public class VMProduct
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }
}
public class VMResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model VMProduct
<form>
    <input type="file" asp-for="ImageFile" />
    <input asp-for="Age" />
    <input asp-for="Name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
            var submittedform = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();   //be sure add this if you use submit button
            submitAJAX(submittedform);
        });
        function submitAJAX(form) {
            var fromData = new FormData();    
            var dataForm = $(form).serializeArray();
            
            $.each(dataForm, function (key, input) {
                fromData.append(input.name, input.value);
            });    
            var file = $("#ImageFile").prop("files");    
            if (file.length > 0) {
                fromData.append("ImageFile", file[0]);
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Product/Create",
                data: fromData,
                method: "post",
                contentType: false,   //be sure add this...
                processData: false,   //be sure add this...
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var data = response;
                    if (data.success) {
                        //do your stuff...
                    }
                    else {
                        //do your stuff...
                    }
                }
            });
        }                       
    </script>
}
```